# UFW not fully loading rules on startup

Tags: debian, firewall, ufw

I have a server with default deny and several UFW rules. UFW is enabled on startup (`systemctl enable UFW`). When I reboot only some of the rules don't get applied properly and I can't access some services. I can SSH into the server, and the lower ports (<1024) seem to work, but  some services above 1024 still drop. If I execute `ufw reload` after a reboot, all begins to run fine.

For example, I have port 3493 allowed for NUT-Server. Always after a reboot this port is non-responsive until I run `ufw reload`:

```
3493                       ALLOW       x.x.x.x/16                # nut-server (UPS)
```

Oddly, however, the Monero port works:

```
18081                      ALLOW       x.x.x.x/24               # Monero
```

When 3493 doesn't work, if I telnet into the machine with telnet x.x.x.x 3493 telnet just waits and never gets a response, indicating to me that the firewall is simply dropping the request, as per my default `ufw default deny`.

Some other posts have pointed to iptables-persistent being the issue. I can confirm iptables-persistent and netfilter-persistent are purged from the system.

`journalctl -u ufw` shows success:

-

```
- Boot f2ba2f00ebfe490f81680a3d43f695f2 --
Jan 23 09:54:15 cryptoDaemon systemd[1]: Finished Uncomplicated firewall.
-- Boot cba07123c3204957ad3490a34d9d1439 --
Jan 23 10:00:45 cryptoDaemon systemd[1]: Finished Uncomplicated firewall.
```

I can confirm ufw is enabled in /etc/ufw/ufw.conf

UPDATE: To test I disabled ufw. Then, after a reboot I ran `iptables -S`. Oddly, there were rules.

Any help getting this working consistently would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case I discovered there were entries in `/etc/iptables.up.rules`. In my case I believe iptables.up.rules existed because of an old edit in Webmin, which I also run.

Moving /etc/iptables.up.rules to /etc/iptables.up.bak and rebooted. The issue is fixed. It turns out I had ifupdown installed and it was loading the firewall rules in /etc/iptables/up.rules. Disabling ifupdown with systemctl disable networking.service fixed the issue